# Searching a char array for a position in the array in C

Tags: c, arrays, search

Not sure if this has been asked, and I don't really know how to ask it: I'm going to post the code I have, and I am aware I'm far off, but I wanted to show that I attempted it and failed.

I will post code then explain it and, then give further information:

```
while(i<41)
{
    if (buffer[i] != 0)
    {
    newplace = i;
    }
    i++;

}
```

buffer is a char array with length of 42. the last spot is a null place holder.

buffer will take in values starting from the END. i goes in reverse order. the problem is when i print it fills in the first positions with 0's, and that gets annoying. What my goal is, is to find the first position that is not a 0, and save that to a variable (newplace) as a place holder. Once that is saved I can print the array with a loop starting from this new place holder. This sounds basic and I'm probably pretty close (or terribly wrong).

I feel once i find the value I need a break in there because then it will keep going and find the next value and change it. Every time I try this it gives me an error.

Also I know that i++ at the end looks stupid. Don't worry I know. I just gave up trying to fix it.

Lastly if there is something i missed let me know. I will edit or add code. thanks.

EDIT: This is what its printing: 000000000000000012345. i want it to print 12345.

EDIT: right now the output goes to the end of the array as in i counts up to 40. it goes to my second print loop and prints newplace, as in it prints out 40, then it prints on the value of the array from 40 to 41. as in the last digit.

EDIT: I feel like I'm getting closer. I modified it so its comparing 2 char arrays instead of array and char.

```
for(;i<41;i++)
    {
        if (buffer[i] != "0123456789ABCDEF"[0])
        {
        newplace = i;

        //break;
        }

    }
```

"0123456789ABCDEF"[0] is all I changed. and what it prints is the last known values where it is not a 0: which means: if there is a 1010 it looks at the LAST 1 and prints 10. I want it to find the FIRST 1.

also with this i tried 100 and it printed 100. but if its 10100 it will print 100, where i want it to print 10100.

Comment: Why not just print in the while loop instead of saving it to another variable?

Comment: because i want to find a starting point.

ie: 000000123 vs 123. thats what im going for.

Comment: But if you print inside of the `if` you'll get `123`...

Comment: `Every time I try this it gives me an error.` Why do people think it's ok to say this but then not tell us what the error is? - You haven't even described in what way it doesn't work!

Comment: but is that the right statement for it?

Comment: John: it gives me a value of 1. and thats not right

Comment: 40 (\n) 0: thats what it prints out with no break. wiht a break it prints out 1(\n)0. \n is just saying new line

Comment: @ZachSaucier but if what we are saying is true, and the if statement should only print non 0 char, then what do we do if its 1203? Thats why I want the place holder

Comment: @dcarney999: what is your input value and what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @Ani I am imputing 2 values for division, storing them in a char array in reverse, printing them out forward. trying to "cut off" leading 0's. I hope my last edit will explain more.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
int start = -1;
while(buffer[i] != 0) { // Assumes 0 terminated array
    if (buffer[i] == '0') {
        start = i;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
if (start >= 0) {
    // start is valid, so do output...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer: but I solved it a different way.

change a thing in my main argument saying that just don't put those values in, so then they are null and then this whole thing is just a waste of time.

i had

```
while(place>0)
```

and changed it to

```
while(place>0 && value != '\0')
```

really out of context becuase I didnt give all my code.

GG WP. Thanks for all the help guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to begin printing at a wanted point in a string that contains additional characters. You can start at the beginning and step down the string until you find the character you desire, or, you can start at the end and work backwards. In either case, you are using a pointer set to where you want to begin your search for wanted characters, then check each character in the string, incrementing or decrementing the pointer, until the desired character is found. The forward direction is straight forward:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char buffer[] = "00000000000000000012345";  /* zero pad buffer and string         */
    char *sp = NULL;                            /* pointer to wamted part of buffer   */

    sp = buffer;                                /* set pointer to beginning of buffer */

    while (sp++) {                              /* for each character in buffer       */
        if (*sp != '0') {                       /* if pointer != '0'                  */
            break;                              /* break, sp points to wanted string  */
        }
    }

    /* print original buffer and wanted end string
    (pointed to by sp) */
    printf ("\n                    buffer  : %s\n", buffer);
    printf ("  sp (wanted end of buffer) : %s\n\n", sp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Build:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/fbuf fwdbuffer.c
```

**Run/Output:**

```
$ ./bin/fwdbuf

                    buffer  : 00000000000000000012345
  sp (wanted end of buffer) : 12345
```

Why work backwards? In numerous circumstances, such as when allocating memory with `calloc` or when the string is set null with `memset`, it is impossible to work in the forward direction. In that case working backwards is the key:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char buffer[] = "00000000000000000012345";  /* zero pad buffer and string        */
    char *sp = NULL;                            /* pointer to filled part of buffer  */
    size_t i = strlen (buffer);                 /* len of buffer (not incl. null  )  */

    sp = buffer + i - 1;                        /* set pointer at buffer null-term   */

    while (sp-- && i--) {                       /* backup in buffer until '0'        */
        if (*sp == '0') {                       /* if pointer == '0'                 */
            sp++;                               /* increment by 1 to last good char  */
            break;                              /* break, sp points to wanted string */
        }
    }

    /* print original buffer and wanted end string
    (pointed to by sp) */
    printf ("\n                    buffer  : %s\n", buffer);
    printf ("  sp (wanted end of buffer) : %s\n\n", sp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Build:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/rbuf revbuffer.c
```

**Run/Output:**

```
$ ./bin/rbuf

                    buffer  : 00000000000000000012345
  sp (wanted end of buffer) : 12345
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.